# how i can set value in Wicket AutoCompleTextField

Tags: java, wicket

I have my AutoCompleteTextField

```
    private class AutoCompleteField extends AutoCompleteTextField<City> {

    public AutoCompleteField(String autoField, HibernateModel<City> selectedWorkTemplate,
                             IAutoCompleteRenderer<City> autoCompleteRenderer) {
        super(autoField, selectedWorkTemplate, autoCompleteRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    protected Iterator<City> getChoices(String input) {
        return input == null ? Collections.emptyIterator() :
                cityRepository.findByNameLike(input).iterator();
    }
}
```

and I declared it like this

```
IAutoCompleteRenderer<City> autoCompleteRenderer = new AbstractAutoCompleteTextRenderer<City>() {
        @Override
        protected String getTextValue(City object) {
            return object.getName();
        }
    };
    cityField = new AutoCompleteField("cityField", selectedCityModel, autoCompleteRenderer);
    form.add(cityField);
```

So, how I can set value by the button, for example?
I try set in selectedCityModel ,but it gave nothing, AutoCompleteTextField dont get/set value to that model.

Comment: how did you try it? what are the methods provided by AutoCompleteTextField<..> ?

Comment: selectedCityModel.setObject(city);    (city is Object of City) ,        and what methods you want see?  he have getChoice(), newAutoCompleteBehavior() etc...    https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/autocomplete/AutoCompleteTextField.html

Comment: Is the parameter `input` in `protected Iterator<City> getChoices(String input)` null?

Comment: not null, but getChoice() is only diplay LIST  of possible choices for user, but dont set anything;

Comment: The documentation says 'To convert input back into a non-String type you will have to provide a custom IConverter'. Did you miss that part?

Comment: @CannedMoose , i saw that, so how i can transfer non-String object to AutoCompleteTextField?  This comment good for take non-string obj from AutoCompleteTextField and transform to string

Answer (score 0):

Changed my class like

```
private class AutoCompleteField extends AutoCompleteTextField<String> {

public AutoCompleteField(String autoField, IModel<String> selectedCityListNameModel) {
    super(autoField, selectedCityListNameModel);
}

@Override
protected Iterator<String> getChoices(String input) {
    return input == null ? Collections.emptyIterator() :
            cityRepository.findByNameLike(input).iterator();
}
```

}

and `selectedCityListNameModel` declaration like

```
private IModel<String> selectedCityListNameModel = Model.of("");
```

so , now AutoCompleteField set and GET value from selectedCityListNameModel (its strange... i think constructor for AutoCompleteTextField with renderer  not working properly)

And now, if i need set not-null value at start for this component, i need to dl: `selectedCityListNameModel.setObject("some String")`, like we need do it for simple TextField